# Convert htaccess for nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I want to convert my htacess for nginx conf. 
Heres my htacess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So whats the htaccess for nginx.conf?

Comment: I try using http://winginx.com/en/htaccess but still not working

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This part appends a trailing `/` to a subset of URIs, and can be accomplished using an `if...return` block:

```
if ($uri !~* /$|\. ) {
    return 301 $uri/$is_args$args;
}
```

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This part is commonly implemented using a `try_files` statement:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.